# Connect Oracle Database using Power Shell without installing .dll

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, powershell, powershell-4.0

I am trying to execute query on oracle DB using Power shell, is there any way to connect oracle DB with power shell without installing ODP.net, i want to connect multiple servers of oracle DB from in house server and it is not possible to install odp.net everywhere.
it would be very helpful if you guys can share an example of power shell connecting to oracle without using .net lib and execute query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See following : https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/ask_the_experts/f/learn_powershell_from_don_jones-24/21346/oracle-odbc-connection-using-dsn-with-powershell

Comment: ok Thanks a lot, it is asking to add a driver to the connection string , does it need to be added some where ?

Comment: Oracle usually requires an ODBC driver installed and then add the driver to the ODBC  Data Sources.

Comment: Well, you are going to have to have _some_ sort of oracle-specific drivers, whether it is odp .net or the native oracle client, or a jdbc thin client.